# ServletContext not able to inject through by passing it as an parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

Hi all i am trying to get ServletContext in my following method but it is not getting injected while passing it as an parameter as it should be injected by the spring automatically but its not working don't know why
this is the following code inside which I want servletcontext

```
@RequestMapping(value="/savetodo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTodo(@ModelAttribute("todoEntity") TodoEntity todoEntity,Model m,ServletContext sc) {
        todoEntity.setTodoDate(new Date());

        ArrayList<TodoEntity> allTodosArrayList =  (ArrayList<TodoEntity>) sc.getAttribute("allTodos");
        if (allTodosArrayList==null) {
            allTodosArrayList = new ArrayList<TodoEntity>();
        }
        allTodosArrayList.add(todoEntity);
        sc.setAttribute("allTodos",allTodosArrayList);
        allTodosArrayList.stream().forEach(System.out :: println);
        m.addAttribute("page","viewtodos");
        return "home";
    }
```

but when I tried using the autowiring by declaring ServletContext as an class variable along with autowired annotation like this and removing the parameter from method

```
@Autowired
ServletContext sc;
```

it just worked fine so my whole point is why it is not working when I am passing it as an **parameter**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServletContext is not one of the auto-resolving method parameters in Spring controllers https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods

Comment: spring is able to inject the dependency  via autowiring and the code is working fine if I use autowiring but it is not injecting dependency when I am passing it as an parameter

Comment: that is not the same. Autowiring happens from application context container. Parameters in Controller Method get resolved by Spring MVC's HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. It is not the same as @Autowiring.

Comment: ok i got you that injecting dependecy through @Autowired is completely different from dependency getting injected through an parameter correct me if i am wrong. and also please do tell me a solution how can I use via parameter.

Comment: Resolving is only limited to a very limited number of resources from web mvc, servlet context is not one of them. The list of auto resolvable arguments is available at the link provided, such as Model, HttpRequest, etc.... You can try `public String saveTodo(@ModelAttribute("todoEntity") TodoEntity todoEntity,Model m, @Autowired ServletContext sc) {...` if you implement your own implementation of servlet context

Comment: is there any other way much more effective than what I am doing to store an ArrayList into the servlet context so that I can access that onto my jsp page thanks.

Comment: yes and you are right you shouldn't be using ServletContext for that. That is what model is for - in your method you add a line `model.addAttribute("allTodos",allTodosArrayList);` and then you will be able to access it in jsp

Comment: but i have to use servlet context because I need something which can hold my ArrayList globally and i want to persist list of todos until my application is running  the model will only help me to take data to my jsp but it wont help me to use that list in another controller hope you understand my problem.

Comment: for that make that arraylist part of a class and that class should be a Spring Bean (you annotate it with @Component). Now thanks to dependency injection that class is available everywhere and so is this arraylist